# How is Chrome able to fetch gist json file? Isn't that forbidden?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am able to fetch json file from Github Gist. However in many other cases i was unable and had to use jsonp, because of cors. How is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any site may accept cross origin requests just sending the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. If the resource owner doesn't send this header, the content will be blocked by the browser. You can read more about [HTTP access control here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).
You can watch the header on your gist if you 1) open the json url in chrome, 2) open the chrome developer tools, 3) select the Network tab, 4) reload the page, 5) and click the json request.